# Database id and listview items id get discrete

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

```
    I am getting stuck with the issue 
    I am getting the All messages from database and shows in list, list having check boxes when I pressed delete then checked check box deleted from database.

       And when I am again click to see all message then all position of the message's get changed but in the database id remain same and further i delete some message then message from database not deleted because position id and database message id become different.

    Please give me any suggestion to solve this issue thank you in advance...
```

- This is my code clicking position and send this position to database but database id are different next time of deletion.

  ```
      OnClickListener listenerDel = new OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                  /** Getting the checked items from the listview */
                  SparseBooleanArray checkedItemPositions = getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();
                  int itemCount = getListView().getCount();

                  for(int i=itemCount-1; i >= 0; i--){
                      if(checkedItemPositions.get(i)){
                          Log.e("position",""+(i+1));


                          adapter.remove(list.get(i));
                          db.deleteMessage(i);
                      }
                  }   
  //              checkedItemPositions.clear();
                  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



              }
          };
  ```

Comment: it is not possible to help you without seeing the soruce code

Comment: Please show us your source code.

Comment: database id remain same but position get changed in listview. SO how can i delete the message from database giving the database id on position click.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a large list and not consistent ID's there can be problems when deleting with an iterator. Try to write a function in your database adapter which takes the item itself not the iterator of the for loop, like that:

```
public void deleteItem(Item item){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_ITEMS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(item.getID())});
    db.close();
}
```